# Running python boto3 inside a docker container requirements on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So, I'm using boto3 s3 with a python script just to list the bucket.

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

It works fine when I run it on my desktop because I setup the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key with my `aws configure` command.

When I run it on AWS as a container, am I going to need to run my container with environment variables for the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key when I use boto3? Or if I have my setup for my container user having access to s3, will that work and negate the need for keys?

Comment: There are many ways to run docker on AWS. How exactly are you doing it? ECS, Fargate, EKS, Ec2 instance, AWS Bash, Lambda and probably more?

Comment: ECS and Fargate is what I plan on using. The question is, when I run my container on those on my aws account, if the user I'm running as has access to S3, would I still need to setup the aws key and secret key in boto3 or will it work off the permissions I give to my task execute user?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to pass permissions to ecs?

Answer (score 1):

> would I still need to setup the aws key and secret key in boto3 or will it work off the permissions I give to my task execute user

You don't have to hard code anything. Instead you provide the permissions using [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html). So S3 permissions are granted through this role. Boto3 will **automatically** inherit the permissions.

Comment: Yep. That did the trick...worked with just IAM.  Thx

Comment: Does it also work if I use aws cli inside the container to copy files from S3?

Comment: @panc yes, it works.

Comment: Thanks. Using a proper IAM role works for me.

Comment: How would this work if the docker isnt actually hosted in AWS , or is running Dockers that talk to AWS just not possible iff the docker isnt running on AWS?

Comment: If "docker isnt actually hosted in AWS " means your `docker run` is running on your own machine, then there are multiple ways to configure credentials for boto3. See [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html). When I test my image locally, I save my credentials in a .env file and pass the file to the container as `docker run  --env-file .env`

Comment: Am I understanding: you can run a `docker` container on an `ec2` and, **automatically**, the `boto3` processes inside that container can use the credentials / IAM policy from the host `ec2` machine? Why does that feel like a security issue... am I missing something?